# What does it mean to "give somebody a pass"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

In [The Wolf of Wall Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(2013_film)) there is a comical scene with Donnie Azoff and Brad Bodnick, where Donnie gets into a public brawl with Brad. Their talk:

> **Brad**: I’m gonna give you a pass. Just give me the case.
>
> **Donnie**: You’re gonna give *me* a pass?
>
> **Brad**: Look, it’s a figure of f*ing speech.
>
> **Donnie**: Oh, my gosh. The Emperor of F..cksville came down form F..cksville to give me a pass!

From the context I may guess that "give a pass" means something like "ok, I’m gonna forgive you this time". Is it so? Does it have some additional meaning?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this context the pass is indeed only a "pass" as in to let the other person go, or; off the hook. In the scene it is most likely comical because Donnie is in some way "lower" than Brad, who i am assuming has money, Brad is certainly dumbfounded that Donnie thinks he controls the situation. But the comedic aspect is that it truly *IS* Donnie who controls it (I don't know the context) and Brad refuses to accept it due to pride. He probably needs Donnie for some reason or another